# How can I create a self join sql query in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a self join SQL query in MS SQL Server that: Displays the CCName of the client and the CCName of the client who referred him or her, for every client referred by a client in the Music industry.

```
SELECT c.CCName,r.CCName AS ReferredBy
FROM CorpClient c, CorpClient r
WHERE c.CCid = r.CCIdReferredby
AND r.CCIndustry = 'Music'
? ;
```

Here is the table:

| CCid | CCName | CCIndustry | CCLocation | CCIdReferredby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C111 | BlingNotes | Music | Chicago | NULL |
| C222 | SkyJet | Airline | Oak Park | C111 |
| C777 | WindyCT | Music | Chicago | C222 |
| C888 | SouthAlps | Sports | Rosemont | C777 |

Comment: A self join is no different to any other join; what is the problem you are having when you try? What is your attempt? Why didn't it work? Also links to images of data don't help us help you. Post sample data in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statement, however, at least well formatted tabular `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your insight and feedback.  I was able to come up with the answer on my own for the following question:

Display the CCName of the client and the CCName of the client who referred him or her, for every client referred by a client in the Music industry.

With the following query:

```
SELECT c.CCName,r.CCName AS ReferredByName
FROM CorpClient c
RIGHT JOIN CorpClient r
ON r.CCId = c.CCIdReferredby
WHERE r.CCIndustry = 'Music';
```

Answer (score 1):

so youre new to this so I will try and explain it easily for you

This is the syntax:

```
 SELECT L.CCName AS ClientName, R.CCName AS ReferredBy
 FROM dbo.CorpClient L 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.CorpClient R ON L.CCid = R.CCidReferredBy
```

There are two important things to learn here - Aliases and Relational data.

Ill start with relational data - its how Relational databases work. Data is often in one table that ties to another table - this is over simplified, so I would suggest reading up on it as its a complex topic with lots of vocabulary that goes with it. Self Join is to imply (Some kind of) JOIN (to the same table) which is a direct implication of relational model to some degree. As you can see in your image, the CCiD and CCidRefferredBy columns have an obvious relationship to each other on the same table. Normally you would be able to review the foreign keys of a table to find these relationships, but they dont always exist. Because our dear friend BlingNotes doesnt have anyone that referred them you have to take special care of which side of the join you want him on, especially if this might need to be a left join, where you want to see all clients and NULL where they have no referring entity. I chose LEFT JOIN to represent this issue to you and have named our aliases to mirror that idea (only for teaching, normally theyd have better names).

That gets us to aliasing - aliasing is important especially in situations like this where you would need to refer to the same objects but different instances of it. You can pretty much alias anything - columns with different names, subqueries, and tables in the from clause with unique names are going to be your most popular. In your scenario aliasing becomes required because you (meaning the compiler) wouldnt know which version of dbo.CorpClient would contain the name of the client versus the name of the referring entity.

Does this help you understand your issue as well as solve it?